# ¿Cómo puedo listar los registro de una API con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

¡Hola! Necesito listar los registro de una API con Javascript. 
Este el error que me genera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el código que desarrolle fue es el siguiente:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'http://mvzexpenses.herokuapp.com/expenses', true);
var data = JSON.parse(this.respuesta);

data.forEach(function(elemento){
console.log(elemento.name);
});
  request.send();
```

Comment: que te responde en this.respuesta? puedes colocar eso en la pregunta? o por lo menos un print de esa respuesta

Comment: Lo que te dice el error es lo que recibe no lo puede interpretar como JSON; hax un `console.log` de `this.respuesta` para ver qué es.

Comment: Me sigue mostrando el mismo error, pensé que era algo que estaba mal en el código pero veo que no es así. Tienen otra manera para listar los registro ?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que esa liga que consultas no es un formato Json, tendrías que acceder a una ruta que te de los datos en JSON, lo cual no sucede.

Comment: @Cig tienes razón, el link de la api no es ta en formato json por eso no lo generaba.